# After cancelling an action to send a delete request to the server, the app crashes

Tags: axios, es6-promise, http-delete, json-server

I'm using axios to make HTTP request

This is my function to delete a user in my database, I'm using json-server which is installed as a dependency

```js
    const deleteThisPerson = (id) => {
        // console.log(`${name} is being deleted`);
        contactServices
            .remove(id)
            .then(() => {
                const currentContacts = persons.filter(person => person.id !== id)
                setPersons(currentContacts)
            })
            .catch(error => console.log(error))
    }
```

and my http delete request is this

```js
const remove = (id) => {
    if (window.confirm(`Delete user?`)) {
        const request = axios.delete(`${baseUrl}/${id}`)
        return request.then(response => response.data)
    } else {
        return false
    }

}
```

I have a `window.confirm()` that pops up when a user tries to delete a resource from the database, it works if I click on `Ok` but crashes if I click on `Cancel`,  I get the following error message `**Uncaught TypeError: _services_persons__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__.default.remove(...).then is not a function**`

How can I correct this?

Answer (score 0):

In the `else` branch, you are returning `false`  which does not have a `then` property (`false.then` is `undefined`). You can use [`Promise.reject`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/reject) to return a rejected promise instead.

```
const remove = (id) => {
  if (window.confirm('Delete user?')) {
    // ...
  } else {
    return Promise.reject(new Error('Request cancelled'))
  }
}
```

You can also omit the `else` clause since you're returning from the `if` branch.

```
const remove = (id) => {
  if (window.confirm('Delete user?')) {
    // ...
  } 
  return Promise.reject(new Error('Request cancelled'))
}
```

Comment: I would do request.reject( //...) in my case? or Promise.reject(//...)

Comment: @utsavojha95 You should use `Promise.reject(...)`.  You cannot call `reject` on `request` and it is block-scoped to the `if` branch.